# Update profile picture through clicking on picture itself Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, profile-picture

I'm trying to find some info online on how to update my user's profile picture on the profile page in the same way that social media applications do it, i.e. by clicking on the profile picture itself and getting asked for the file upload straight away. However, all I'm finding online is options to create a form to do that job, but then it's going to be an upload button that does the job, which is not the same.

**How do I get the image to be clickable, opening a file upload after I click it that would then update my model ImageField?**

Comment: try to edit your question and  add jquery ,javascriscript to your tags.this will help you, i think here you have to use js and django together.